# You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders. (./node_modules/superstruct/dist/index.mjs 24:23)

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, babel-loader

```
./node_modules/superstruct/dist/index.mjs 24:23
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (24:23)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|     } = failure;
|     const msg = path.length === 0 ? message : `At path: ${path.join('.')} -- ${message}`;
>     super(explanation ?? msg);
|     if (explanation != null) this.cause = msg;
|     Object.assign(this, rest);
```

I got these errors after start using `@coinbase/wallet-sdk`

I tried to change tsconfig.json

```
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "es6",
      "ScriptHost",
      "ES2016.Array.Include"
    ]`
```

But it does not help me